# How to set variable value with conditional in one line?

Tags: linux, bash, operators

Have this:

```
DATABASE_HOST=[ $# -le 3 ] && $3 || '127.0.0.1';
```

But does not works. Is a bash script with 3 optional parameters:

```
db.sh user dbname hostname
```

I want to replace my old method:

```
if [ $# -le 3 ]
then
    DATABASE_HOST=$3;
else
    DATABASE_HOST='127.0.0.1';
fi
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can shorten it with this BASH construct:

```
DATABASE_HOST="${3:-127.0.0.1}"
```

As per `man bash`:

```
${parameter:-word}
  Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. 
  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```